# SWRevealViewController doesn't show the rear view when the bar button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

After making a sample project watching a tutorial video, I implemented the class onto my actual project but I still have difficulty opening the slide menu with a UIBarButtonItem.

[image]

`imzm` is the front view controller; while `mypage(sidemenu)` is the slide view controller which is hidden by `imzm` and shows up from the right side of the screen.

in the 'Storyboard segue' tab, I set identifiers as follows:

```
Reveal View Controller -> mypage(sidemenu):sw_right
Reveal View Controller -> Vc info Navigation: sw_front
mypage(sidemenu) -> imzm: myPage
```

In the `UIViewController` class for vc `imzm`, I wrote the following codes in the method `viewDidLoad()`:

```
listBarBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 293
listBarBtn.action =
        #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

These are all things I checked. And these features are all the same as those of the sample project, which button worked well.

The only difference I can notice is that the navigation bar of my project has to UIBarButtonItems, not one. But I don't think this makes any difference..

I can still make the app show the slide menu when the background of the front view controller is slid from right to left! I cannot figure out why the button does not work.

Comment: you r using wrong seague identifier. instead of sw_right you have to use sw_rear. So it will work now

Comment: @Jecky Nothing changes. Moreover, The identifier in the same position of the sample project I tested has `sw_right` too and it works well.

Comment: check out my storyboard .https://gist.github.com/jitendrabenzatine/24a63998b4ae90c89550ab7c76fdec5f It work perfectly for me

Comment: I compared mine to yours and everything was the same.. I just deleted all the connections between the view controllers and linked back; and also added one more UIBarButtonItem and It was totally okay.

Comment: I think it was because the UIBarButtonItem I used contained a UIButton within it... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you